# Please help me understand this Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I've been working at an online course and I was wondering if someone could break down what is going on with the .each function in this code.

```
puts "Enter data"
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split

frequencies = Hash.new(0)

words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
```

Comment: For each word in words array, the frequency of the word increment by one. (It is like reading English)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I understand what is happening but I need clarification on the why. I'm unclear as to what frequencies[word] does exactly.

Comment: Here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: It's a Hash, or a hash-table, otherwise known as a dictionary. It's like an array except the key isn't a numerical value, but something arbitrary. These are really useful data structures for organizing things.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the break down:

```
# Prints "Enter data" to the console
puts "Enter data"

# Ask for user input, remove any extra line breaks and save to text variable
text = gets.chomp

# Splits the text string to an array of words
words = text.split

# Create a new Hash, with default values of 0
frequencies = Hash.new(0)

# For each word in the array, increment 1 to the value in the frequencies hash.
# If the key doesn't exist yet, it will be assigned the value 0, since it is the default and then have 1 incremented to it
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
```

In the end you will have a Hash where each key is a word in `text` and the values are the number of times each word appeared.

Comment: Thanks victor you're the best <3

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is that in Ruby it's necessary to initialize the hash with a default of `0` because `nil += 1` is not a valid operation. Other languages automatically cast to integer values when necessary so this might seem confusing at first. In Ruby you need to initialize with a baseline number, which in this case is zero.

Comment: It's perhaps useful to point out that `frequencies[word] += 1` is syntatic sugar for `frequencies[word] = frequencies[word]  + 1`. When Ruby finds, on the right side, that `frequencies` does not have a key `word`, it assigns `word` the default value, `0`, so that `frequencies[word]  => 0`, and the expression therefore becomes `frequencies[word] = 0+1`.